# Increment a column in table based on another table

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 table in my database.

Table #1

```
----------------------------
| name | id | overdue_days |
----------------------------
```

Table #2

```
-------------
| name | id | 
-------------
```

This is to maintain a fine collection database where `overdue_days` in table #1 corresponds to how many days the fine submission by a particular id pending is done.

Table #2 receives every day the names of defaulters for that day.

My intention is to compare table #1 and table #2 and

1. Increment the overdue days for ids which are present in table #2 and are already present in table #1.
2. If a particular id is present in table #1 but not in table #2 , then set its overdue days to 0.
3. If an id is present in table #2 but not in table #1, insert a row for it with overdue days as value 1.

My desired result would be updated table #1 with the above conditions.

I can think of one way to use three separate join queries and cover each of the cases.

```
update T1
set overdue_days = overdue_days + 1
from table#1 T1
inner join table#2 T2
on T1.id = T2.id;
```

Is there an optimised way to do the above?

Comment: Does the `table#1.id` field has the unique constraint (primary key or unique index)?

Comment: The solutions might differ depending on the RDBMS you base your database on. Will you be using PostgreSQL or MySQL? Or do you require a generic solution?

Comment: I will be using postgresql.

Comment: why not just make a calculated column in table 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For MySQL only.**

If the `id` field in the `table1` is primary key or has unique constraint, the solution can consist of 2 queries:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 (name, id, overdue_days)
SELECT name, id, 0
FROM table2;

UPDATE table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id
SET table1.overdue_days = CASE WHEN table2.id IS NULL 
                               THEN 0 
                               ELSE table1.overdue_days+1 
                          END;
```

- If record present in table1 only, it is not affected by Q1 and `overdue_days` is set to 0 by Q2.
- If record present in both tables, it is not affected by Q1 and `overdue_days` is incremented by Q2.
- If record present in table2 only, it is inserted by Q1 with `overdue_days` = 0, and then is incremented by Q2.

**For PostgreSQL.**

> *PostgreSQl is not my favorite DBMS, some mistakes possible*

```
INSERT INTO table1 (name, id, overdue_days)
SELECT name, id, 1
FROM table2
ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET overdue_days = overdue_days+1;

UPDATE table1
SET overdue_days = 0
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table2
                  WHERE table1.id = table2.id);
```

- If record present in table1 only, it is not affected by Q1 and `overdue_days` is set to 0 by Q2.
- If record present in both tables, it's `overdue_days` is incremented by Q1 and is not affected by Q2.
- If record present in table2 only, it is inserted into table1 by Q1 with `overdue_days` = 1, which is not affected by Q2.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I need a solution for postgresql.

Comment: @raizsh: For the record, the Postgres version is perfect. I would suggest the same. Consider accepting the answer.

Comment: The answer was edited after my comment. I think I was able to come up with the answer later, so was not able to check the answer shared above. Since you mentioned that this is correct, I will go ahead and accept the solution. Thank you!